# How to format the text as bold , underline in XSLT

Tags: html

I've got some XML piece of code.
I would like to use XSLT to transform it into HTML .
The problem is that I would like to format the output text as bold and underline.
But I don't know how to format text as bold and underline in XSLT.

Would you please help me?
Please provide some example code for this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

If you're producing HTML, then you format using HTML:

```
<b>bold</b> <u>underline</u> <strong>strong</strong>
```

...or CSS:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">
   bold underlined
</span>
```